# Access different sub directories of a parent directory using command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

**Issue**

I need to create a script(Batch file) to run it on Command prompt in order to delete a set of files present in different sub folders( all sub folders have same name with 1,2,3,4... and so on at the end).

**Example**

`D:\Users\zakwkhan\Desktop\New folder\S1` & `D:\Users\zakwkhan\Desktop\New folder\S2`, and the Problem is that the folders are not limited and will increase as time passes. If it would have been only one folder then I could have used

```
forfiles /p "D:\Users\zakwkhan\Desktop\New folder\New folder\S1" /m * /s /c "cmd /c echo @file"
```

Is there any while loop present in command prompt which I can use with this command so that I can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need two nested `for` loops; one to get the folders, the other one to get the files in each of those folders:

```
for /d %%a in ("D:\Users\zakwkhan\Desktop\New folder\S*") do (
  for %%b in ("%%a\*") do 
    echo %%b
  )
)
```